# list from jquery ajax not showing up properly

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have an ajax call which creates a list based on what is returned:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "Home/FillTags",
    data: "{ 'mydataishere' }",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function (msg) {
     $('.placetags').html('');
     $('.placetags').append("<div class=\"tags\">");
        var i = 0;           
        $.each(msg, function () {
            $('.placetags').append("<li><a href='javascript:void(0)' onclick=\"fnKeyWordSearch({'type' : '2' , 'tag' : '" + msg[i].TagID + "'});\"> " + msg[i].Tag + "</a></li>");
            i++;
        });
     $('.placetags').append("</div>");
    }
});
```

The ajax is returning proper list ,This is what I would like to see as rendered HTML :

```
<div class="placetags">
  <div class="tags">
    <li>...</li>
    <li>...</li>
    <li>...</li>
  </div>
</div>
```

But... This is what I am getting ...

```
<div class="placetags">
  <div class="tags"></div>
    <li>...</li>
    <li>...</li>
    <li>...</li>    
</div>
```

I do not understand why the `.tags` div is being closed before the `<li>`'s are put into it.  My css is written expecting to style `<li>`'s that are inside of `.tags`  , I do not understand why this is happening.

Comment: You can't append partial elements... How about making creating a string the appending it all at once?  or append the li's to the div you just created

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just an improper nesting, try this:

```
$('.placetags').append("<div class=\"tags\">");
    var i = 0;           
    $.each(msg, function () {
        $('.tags').append("<li><a href='javascript:void(0)' onclick=\"fnKeyWordSearch({'type' : '2' , 'tag' : '" + msg[i].TagID + "'});\"> " + msg[i].Tag + "</a></li>");
        i++;
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

This is because each(!) call to .append() will add a complete HTML element, including its content and its closing tag!

If you want to avoid this, you'd have to create the full HTML to be appended first, and only use .append() when the HTML is complete.

Comment: is that new ?  I feel like i've been able to append parts of HTML elements , I did just update my jquery to 1.8.3

Comment: No, you can always only create full elements, but (as you can see from the other answers) you can still append sub elements to the new element later

Answer (score 0):

You need to append it to the div you just created.. not the container div again

```
$('.placetags').append("<div class=\"tags\" />"); // <-- make sure you close or it breaks in IE
        var i = 0;           
        $.each(msg, function () {
            $('.placetags div.tags').append("<li><a href='javascript:void(0)' onclick=\"fnKeyWordSearch({'type' : '2' , 'tag' : '" + msg[i].TagID + "'});\"> " + msg[i].Tag + "</a></li>");
            i++;
        });
```

Comment: that works , travis was just 3 min faster for the similar answer

Comment: @ScottSelby Oo.. You mean 3 minutes slower.. but it's ok